# Way to design user permission check

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to this codeigniter. I am building a application where in user roles play a important role. In a controller i want to check if user has a particular role or permission and then give access to functions. I was wondering if i can create a flow such that i don't need to check permissions or roles for each controller, when extending only this can be done. Can i do so?

/** Update **/

How will i do if i want to set permissions for each method in a controller or only some methods in a controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <?php
class Secure_area extends CI_Controller 
{

    function __construct($module_id=null)
    {
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->model('Employee');
        if(!$this->Employee->is_logged_in())
        {
            redirect('login');
        }

        if(!$this->Employee->has_permission($module_id,$this->Employee->get_logged_in_employee_info()->person_id))
        {
            redirect('no_access/'.$module_id);
        }

        //load up global data
        $logged_in_employee_info=$this->Employee->get_logged_in_employee_info();
        $data['allowed_modules']=$this->Module->get_allowed_modules($logged_in_employee_info->person_id);
        $data['user_info']=$logged_in_employee_info;
        $this->load->vars($data);
    }
}
?>
```

put every thing  that you want to do first in __construct....

Comment: do we need to check anything in session or not?

Comment: of caurse we do? $this->Employee->is_logged_in() (defined in 'Empployee' model) will lookin to session for userdata('some variable') and returns 'true' or 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i developed one system where i faced same problem...folowing is solution for my problem

1. one table that stores all contoller name(or module in my problem).
    e.g. mod1
         mod2 
         mod3
          .
          .
2. one table that stores user access permission for all controllers 
   e.g   user1   mod1    0
        user1   mod2    1
        user1   mod3    1
          .
          .
        user2   mod1    1
        user2   mod2    0
        user2   mod3    1
3. created on file(secure_area.php EXTENDS CI_Controller) that checks is_logged_in(){yes:has_permission(){yes:do things....continue, no:redirect(permission denied)},   no:(redirect(login)) }
4. And all my controllers extends secure_area.php.
5. In admin area you can crate function or form that grants permission to users using simply check boxes.

Comment: But ur checking permission in parent class. But in parent class i wont know which controller is being called rite?

Comment: but child class is extending parent class...that is code in parent class is part of child class..basically for user1 ....www.example.com/index.php/mod1/function/arg....will redirect him to permission denied page......but www.example.com/index.php/mod2/function/arg....will allow him access

Comment: require_once ("secure_area.php"); mod1 EXTENDS secure_area

Comment: Ok i got that point. But how do i make sure that permission check happens 1st when a function i called?